# Cocos2d C++ Identify CCSprites with UserData?

Tags: c++, windows, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, user-data

I am stuck in my Game cause I have to much Sprites in CCArrays.
I identify the function of the Sprite on it's Tags, but it's not working, cause I only can use Ints as Tag. So I decided to make UserData like this:

```
int* nums = new int(2);
background->setUserData((void*)nums);

int* data = (int*)background->getUserData();
if(data == 2){  //this line makes the error C2446
    //do some code
}
```

I need some way to identify my sprites that better than tags?
How do I get the UserData to work?
Is there another good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dereference the pointer:

```
if(*data == 2){  //this line makes the error C2446
    //do some code
}
```